# Presenting a yearly data from a CVS/XLSX on a WEB PAGE (html) and simulate a Real-Time

Tags: web-apps, javascript, html, web-development, php

I am an electrical engineer, new in the web developing area, I used to program in Python, Basic SQL queries SQLite and electrical software.

What I need:

1. I have a file (CVS or xlsx) that contains two columns with values per every 15 minutes during one complete year (a time series).
2. I need to **present in a WEB PAGE**, the info contained in that file (CVS or xlsx), by **showing a table with some data filters** (such a time period, ascending order, descending order, etc).
3. The web page has to simulate a **"Real-Time behavior"**, thats mean, that **the web page has to read and present the data every 15 minutes** according to with the internal clock of the computer (or server)
4. Then, I have to plot those values in "real-time" in a **scatter diagram**.

Any suggestions about which software to use for that (PHP, JS, ...) or third application?

Comment: Any, please?   I really nee to start

Answer (score 1):

What I did was:

1. Reading the actual server date and time in PHP.
2. Make a CRUD with SQlite3 and PHP for accessing the Table.
3. I use DATA TABLES from Bootstrap for presenting the table
4. I pull the data to the table with a while in PHP.
5. I reload the web page automatically every 15 minutes with a PHP command as explained here: [Dynamic background color of an web object (in a web page) depending a reading value from a CVS file](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69651/dynamic-background-color-of-an-web-object-in-a-web-page-depending-a-reading-va)

Comment: This is how I would have done it - except for step 5. Simpler is a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15">` tag in the HTML `<header>`. It is ok to accept your own answer. Doing so could help others in future. Sorry that I dind't see this question earlier, but congratulations on finding a solution :-)